# SQL: to_char alternative for Oracle AND SQL-Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, to-char

I have some sql statements, which i am using for Oracle. This sql statements are used by a programm from me. 
I want to support Oracle and SQL-Server with my program without having different sql statements for Oracle and SQL-Server.

Which alternative can i use for the specific Oracle SQL-Statements:

- to_char(FIELDNAME, 'YYYY')
- to_char(FIELDNAME, 'YYYYMMDD')
- to_char(FIELDNAME, 'DD.MM.YYYY')

The sql statements have to work for Oracle **and** SQL-Server.

Comment: Select the dates as dates from your databases and format them with application code.

Comment: If you want such a function, you need to write it yourself. But even then you can't use the same syntax for both DBMS as SQL Server _always_ requires fully qualified function names (e.g. `select dbo.my_tochar(...) ..`) whereas this is not required in Oracle (and you usually don't have a schema `dbo` just for the functions). Another option is to define a view that returns the formatted date using DBMS specific functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if at a first glance the SQL implementation from two different vendors looks similar, when working with real life enterprise applications you will stumble upon a large number of differences, and I am only talking about SQL, when comparing PL/SQL with T-SQL there is hardly any resemblance left.

When trying to reduce the usage of two databases to only common functionality, you will loose a lot of their power, you could as well use a txt file on the file system.

One elegant solution, as someone already suggested, would be to leave the columns in the database as DATE data type and extract your data in the application code that stands above the database, if any. For example, in Java, you will map your database DATE columns to java.sql.Date no matter if that date comes from Oracle or from SQL Server.

Still, if you want to get your formatted data from the database, you could create separate columns that hold the formatted date, for example :

FIELDNAME | FIELDNAME_YYYY | FIELDNAME_YYYYMMDD | FIELDNAME_DDMMYYYY

Comment: The program is an interface. So my solution to set the input format works fine for me. The interface collects data only and writes it into an output file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are common functions to do what you want.  Oracle supports the ANSI standard `extract()` function for extracting date parts.  SQL Server has separate functions for `YEAR()`, `MONTH()`, and `DAY()`.  Oracle uses `TO_CHAR()`; SQL Server uses `CONVERT()`.

One option is to define the functions `YEAR()`, `MONTH()`, and `DAY()` in Oracle and then use string concatenation (via the `CONCAT()`) function to combine the data.  Or, write specific functions in each database for what you want to do.  Or, perhaps, someone has implemented `TO_CHAR()` in SQL Server and you can grab the code from the web.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found a solution. Maybe its useful some other people too.

You can set the input format for a date...

Oracle: `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD.MM.YYYY'`
SQL-Server: `SET DATEFORMAT dmy`